# How to configure python-rclone?

Tags: python, rclone

I installed the package **rclone** in Debian server and It's work.

> rclone ls mygdrive:mypath

Now, I want to use *rclone* in my *python* script so I installed **python-rclone**

> pip install python-rclone

But how can I configure it to use the main config file `/root/.rclone.conf` or any other solution?

Comment: Can you add your Python code?

Answer (score 7):

Try this.

```
import rclone

cfg_path = r'/root/.rclone.conf'

with open(cfg_path) as f:
   cfg = f.read()

result = rclone.with_config(cfg).listremotes()
```

`with_config` expects `cfg` as string. Look at the example here - https://github.com/ddragosd/python-rclone#usage

Comment: The line 'result = rclone.with_config(cfg).listremotes()' got the error 'NameError: global name 'FileNotFoundError' is not defined' :(

Comment: My code is exactly your sample code. My rclone config file is /root/.rclone.conf and the command 'rclone ls gdrive:path/foo' on OS is working correctly. But this python code is not!

Comment: Can you atleast add the complete traceback in your question?

Comment: This man deserves an accepted answer for this. This worked great for me!